# Parse integer string (larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE)

Tags: java, integer

Say I have this string `0xdadacafe` (which is obviously greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE: `0x7fffffff`). If I used `Integer.parseInt(String, int)` to parse it, I would get a `NumberFormatException`. Is there any way to parse this string and get a 'silent' overflow?

In other words, is there any way to parse this string and get `-623195394`, which is the value you'd get if you do `System.out.println(0xdadacafe);`

(And I probably wouldn't want to do something like `(int)Long.parseLong(String, int)` )

Thanks

Comment: No way, you have to do the dirty hack proposed as what you don't want to do

Comment: Is [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28java.lang.String%29) is also not OK for you

Answer (score 4):

You can read it in as a [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) and then return the correct int value.

```
BigInteger value = new BigInteger("dadacafe", 16); // 3671771902
value.intValue(); // -623195394
```

**Edit:**

re: comments saying this is slow..

I mean, [there's always this right](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.parseInt%28java.lang.String,int%29):

```
public static int parseInt(String s, int radix)
    throws NumberFormatException
{
    if (s == null) {
      throw new NumberFormatException("null");
    }

    if (radix < Character.MIN_RADIX) {
      throw new NumberFormatException("radix " + radix +
          " less than Character.MIN_RADIX");
    }

    if (radix > Character.MAX_RADIX) {
      throw new NumberFormatException("radix " + radix +
          " greater than Character.MAX_RADIX");
    }

    int result = 0;
    boolean negative = false;
    int i = 0, len = s.length();
    int digit;

    if (len > 0) {
      char firstChar = s.charAt(0);
      if (firstChar < '0') { // Possible leading "-"
        if (firstChar == '-') {
          negative = true;
        } else
          throw new NumberFormatException(s);

        if (len == 1) // Cannot have lone "-"
          throw new NumberFormatException(s);
        i++;
      }
      while (i < len) {
        // Accumulating negatively avoids surprises near MAX_VALUE
        digit = Character.digit(s.charAt(i++),radix);
        if (digit < 0) {
          throw new NumberFormatException(s);
        }
        result *= radix;
        result -= digit;
      }
    } else {
      throw new NumberFormatException(s);
    }
    return negative ? result : -result;
}
```

But at this point, I would start to think that maybe this isn't solving the problem correctly. I'm not sure if you're railing up against existing software, or what the situation may be, but if 'fast-as-light' int overflows is actually something you truly need - it probably won't get much better than this.

Comment: While this indeed works, it appears to execute approximately 3 times slower than the `Long.parseLong` approach does.

Comment: Well, I'll give you the context. I'm writing a Java compiler in Java (I know it sounds unethical, but hey, why not?). So the literal ints are scanned as strings which need to be parsed. Naturally, one would think of `Integer.parseInt()`, but that would throw the `NumberFormatException` for this case `int x = 0xdadacafe;`. The `jdk` would actually assign a value of `-623195394` to `x` because it lets the hex-string 'silently' overflow.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
int i = (int)Long.parseLong("0xdadacafe".substring(2), 16);
```

Comment: Well, that's what I said I rather not do. And the reason is that the number could also be something that is larger than a `long`, which will have raised a `NumberFormatException`. I'm looking for some API, if there exists one, that could do the parsing and which would allow the number to 'silently' overflow

Comment: @user1508893 The `BigInteger` approach will handle values larger than `long`'s max values.

Comment: @user1508893 right, you did mention it and I didn't notice, but you must agree that it was a bit confusing, cause the title says "Parse integer string (larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE)"

Comment: Yeah, sorry, by integer, I meant 'integral' (whole number)